# RVM do not works on RHEL EC2 with CodeDeploy after reboot

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rvm, aws-code-deploy

I have an RHEL 7.6 EC2 instance, I manually installed rvm for root user. Then used code-deploy agent to deploy my application. It all works fine as I use `rvm` in my before/after install codedeploy shell scripts. Once the reboot happens OR you have an AMI baked with the RVM already, we get the following errors, ONLY for codedeploy deployment. Normal ssh works fine.

```
[stderr]/bin/bash: __rvm_ruby_string_find: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `(' 
[stderr]/bin/bash: __rvm_ruby_string_find: line 8: ` ruby-+([1-9]) | ruby-+([1-9]).+([0-9]) | ruby-1.+([1-9]).+([0-9]) | jruby-[19]*)'
```

I tried `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` looking at [this][1]
And also tried `/bin/bash --login` looking at [this][2], But did not work.
doing `which rvm` shows me the path to rvm binary. But `rvm use`, `rvm help`... `rvm <anything at all>` is not working, throwing the same error.